# Can multiple android and ios applications be made in a single Flutter project?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

In a flutter project, I have a file structure as follows;

```
my_flutter_project/
  -android_x/
  -android_y/
  -ios_x/
  -ios_y/
  -lib/
    - main_x.dart
    - main_y.dart
  - pubspec.yaml
```

When I run main_x it should run ios_x or android_x, when I run main_y it should run ios_y or android_y. How can I set this?